# Angular 7 & JQWidgets - Export Grid data from another component

Tags: angular, angular7, jqwidget

I am experimenting with Angular 7 and JQWidgets. I am working on Grid component and want to export Grid's data from another component called settings. 
I worked on the demo (available [here](https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-grid/#https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-grid/angular-grid-dataexport.htm)) and I created the following component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { jqxDropDownListComponent } from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxdropdownlist';
import { jqxGridComponent } from 'jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets-ts/angular_jqxgrid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mydemo',
  templateUrl: './mydemo.component.html'
})

export class MydemoComponent{
    @ViewChild('myGrid') myGrid: jqxGridComponent;
    @ViewChild('myDropDownList') myDropDownList: jqxDropDownListComponent;

    exportFiletype: any;

    constructor() { }

    exportBtnOnClick() {
        this.exportFiletype = this.myDropDownList.getSelectedItem().value;
        switch (this.exportFiletype) {
            case 'Excel':
                this.myGrid.exportdata('xls', 'jqxGrid', true, null, true, 'https://jqwidgets.com/export_server/dataexport.php');
                break;
            case 'CSV':
                this.myGrid.exportdata('csv', 'jqxGrid', true, null, true, 'https://jqwidgets.com/export_server/dataexport.php');
                break;
        };
    };
}
```

My problem is with this.myGrid referrring to the Grid in the other component. How can I refer straight to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated as per new information:-

Use one of the https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction models to interact between components.

Following is the example of template variables.

**Main Component**

```
//showing only html

<my-grid #myGrid><my-grid>
<my-dropdown [grid]="myGrid.jqxGrid"><my-dropdown>
```

**Component A (my-dropdown)**

Use `onSelect` and you can pass in your myDropDownList reference as well that way you can pass whatever reference you will

Bind to the select event of jqxDropDownList.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-dropdown",
    template: `
        <jqxDropDownList #myDropDownList (onSelect)="exportTo($event)"
            [width]="200" [height]="25" [source]="source" [selectedIndex]="1">
        </jqxDropDownList>
    `
})

export class MyDropDown{
    @Input() grid: jqxGridComponent
    exportTo(event: any): void 
    {
        if (this.grid) {
            this.grid.doSomething()
        }
    }

    source: string[] =
    [
        'Affogato',
        'Americano',
        'Bicerin',
        'Breve'
    ];
}
```

**Component B - Grid component**

```
template: `
<jqxGrid #jqxGrid [theme]="'material'"
    [width]="getWidth()" [source]="dataAdapter" [columns]="columns"
    [pageable]="true" [autoheight]="true" [sortable]="true" 
    [altrows]="true"  [enabletooltips]="true"  [editable]="true" 
    [selectionmode]="'multiplecellsadvanced'" [columngroups]="columngroups">
</jqxGrid>
`
export class MyGrid {
     @ViewChild('jqxGrid') jqxGrid: jqxGridComponent;
}
```

Comment: But my Grid is in another component. I want to export data in component A from a component B. How do I write this.myGrid.exportdata differently?

Comment: Is A to B parent child relationship or they are siblings ?

Comment: They are siblings

Comment: I updated the answer - but it is just one way to do it but I encourage you to refer to https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Use @ContntChild